# remove columns from woocommerce product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am trying to limit the options certain users have when viewing the products list within woocommerce for wordpress admin pages.

```
if( current_user_can('vendor') ) {
function my_columns_filter( $columns ) {

    unset($columns['tags']);
    unset($columns['featured']);
    unset($columns['type']);
    return $columns;
}
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'my_columns_filter', 10, 1 );
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong.

Place `if/else` inside the function instead of wrapping the function.

```
function my_columns_filter( $columns ) {
    if( current_user_can('vendor') ) {
        unset($columns['tags']);
        unset($columns['featured']);
        unset($columns['type']);

        return $columns;
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'my_columns_filter', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct column names, or perhaps WC has changed them since you posted your question. It also better to check if a column still exists before removing it in case WC does change their column names.

Here is a future proof solution you can past into your theme's functions.php:

```
function my_product_columns_filter( $columns ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'vendor' ) ) {
        foreach ( array( 'product_tag', 'featured', 'product_type' ) as $name ) {
            if ( isset( $columns[ $name ] ) ) {
                unset( $columns[ $name ] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'my_product_columns_filter' );
```

**no coding solution**

If you're just looking for a quick solution without the need for coding, you could use the free [admin columns plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/codepress-admin-columns) from wordpress.org, which allows you to add and remove columns with a few clicks.