# WooCommerce: How to hide the tags, featured, and type columns in the admin's products list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have tried the following answers but they didn't work: [remove columns from woocommerce product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071422/remove-columns-from-woocommerce-product-page)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually easier to do than I thought. You can hide any of the columns from "Screen Options" at the top right of the products page. Simply uncheck the boxes of the columns that you wish to hide. No code needed {=

Comment: Comment from [Melissa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8585039/melissa) (posted as answer but might get removed): "_Just a note: hiding the tags and categories, etc. on screen options only hides them on the back-end (i.e. what YOU see while you edit the page.) It does not hide them from the front end (what the visitor sees) if that is something your theme shows._"

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce has changed a little bit since 2014…

Here is the working and tested code for last WooCommerce version:

```
function unset_some_columns_in_product_list( $column_headers ) { 
        unset($column_headers['product_tag']);
        unset($column_headers['featured']);
        unset($column_headers['product_type']);

        return $column_headers;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'unset_some_columns_in_product_list' );
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*